# Getting error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Tags: java, android, directory

I have this error, what I am trying to do is read a .csv file so that I can retrieve its data and enter it into a local database.

This is my code:

In my android Manifest, I have these permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

In my class I have the following code:

```
public void importarCSV() {

    File carpeta = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/BaseDeDatosAlumnos");
    String archivo = carpeta + "/" + "prueba.csv";


    if (!carpeta.exists()) {
        Toast.makeText(ActividadPrincipalAdmin.this, "NO EXISTE LA CARPETA", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        String cadena;
        String[] arreglo;
        try {
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(archivo);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

            while ((cadena = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                arreglo = cadena.split(",");

                //CARGA DE CLASES Y CREACION DE OBJETOS PARA FUNCIONAMIENTO DE LA DB
                DbHelper admin = new DbHelper(ActividadPrincipalAdmin.this);
                SQLiteDatabase db = admin.getWritableDatabase();

                ContentValues registro = new ContentValues();

                registro.put("nControl", arreglo[1]);
                registro.put("nombre", arreglo[2]);
                registro.put("carrera", arreglo[3]);
                registro.put("semestre", arreglo[4]);
                registro.put("genero", arreglo[5]);

                db.insert("t_alumnos", null, registro);

                Toast.makeText(ActividadPrincipalAdmin.this, "SE IMPORTO CORRECTAMENTE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(ActividadPrincipalAdmin.this, "- " + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Toast.makeText(ActividadPrincipalAdmin.this, "LO LAMENTO TIENES UN ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is how I request the permissions:

```
public void pedirPermisos() {
    int permisoEscritura = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    int permisoLectura = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (permisoEscritura != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && permisoLectura != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                Manifest.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, RecuestCode);
    }
}
```

I tried to change the folder and my file to other folders but it doesn't work, just like I tried to put direct paths of my folder but it didn't work either.

Comment: If it didn't work, there must be an error output dump, please show.

Comment: Add: `if(!new File(archivo).canRead()) return;` before you try to read.

Comment: But you should check if the file exists and if you can read the file instead of the directory.

Comment: blackapps I already put what you told me and now I can't read the file. Any suggestions as to why this happens?